# how to complete my proof of $(A\cup B)\triangle(A\cup C) \subseteq A \cup (\ B \triangle C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

\begin{align} (A\cup B)\triangle(A\cup C) \subseteq A \cup (\ B \triangle C) \end{align}

Here is my proof:

\begin{align} x \in (A\cup B)\triangle(A\cup C) \end{align}
def. $\triangle$
\begin{align} x \in (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cup C) \land  x \in (A\cup C)\setminus (A\cup B)  \end{align}
simp.
\begin{align} x \in (A\cup B)\setminus (A\cup C)\end{align}
def. $\setminus$
\begin{align} x \in (A\cup B) \land x \notin (A\cup C)\end{align}

and I'm stuck

Comment: How can we check something which is *not* a proof? A proof cannot end with “I'm stuck”.

Comment: I corrected it thanks for alerting :)

Answer (score 2):

Take $x\in(A\cup B)\triangle(A\cup C)$. Then $x$ belongs to one of the sets $A\cup B$ and $A\cup C$, but not to both.

Suppose that $x\in A\cup B$. Then $x\in A$ or $x\in B$. But if $x\in A$, then $x\in A\cup C$, which is impossible, since we are assuming that $x$ doesn't belong to both sets $A\cup B$ and $A\cup C$. So, $x\in B$. And, since $x\notin A\cup C$, $x\notin C$. So, $x\in B\triangle C$. And so, since $A\cup(B\triangle C)\supseteq B\triangle C$, $x\in A\cup(B\triangle C)$.

The same argument shows that if $x\in A\cup C$, then $x\in A\cup(B\triangle C)$. Since this occurs for each $x\in(A\cup B)\triangle(A\cup C)$…

Comment: yes I should've put or not and...